# XML parser issue with yahoo weather API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am stuck in how to parse this kind of XML (with same element name)

```
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="18 Dec 2009" low="49" high="62" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" />
<yweather:forecast day="Sat" date="19 Dec 2009" low="49" high="65" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" />
```

Link to full xml response: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

I used this XML parser method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:forecast"]) {
    if(_data1) {
        [_data1 release];
    }

    _data1 = [attributeDict retain];
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:forecast"]) {
    if(_data2) {
        [_data2 release];
    }

    _data2 = [attributeDict retain];
}
}
```

What I want is weather info for friday into data1 Dictionay & weather info for satday into data2 dictionary

But currently I am getting only for one day (last element name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array and do something like this

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:forecast"]) {
    [array addObject:attributeDict];
}
```

This array will hold your data for all the days

Comment: You can also use this google xml..         http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=hyderabad+India

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this google xml..

http://google.com/ig/api?weather=hyderabad+India

Hope this helps you.